# How to do mutiple css class in one line javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I have css class names - .exp-1 , .exp-2, .exp-3 , exp-4 ... 
so is there any simple way to write these all in onlike line like ,I m beginner to javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("exp-1")[0];
document.getElementsByClassName("exp-2")[0];
document.getElementsByClassName("exp-3")[0];
document.getElementsByClassName("exp-4")[0];
```

to

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("exp-1,exp-2,exp-3, exp-4")[0];
```

Comment: Give them all the same class name? It would be the point of a classname? Elements can have multiple class names... or just simply use `.querySelector()`

Comment: You might want to update the question ; you seem to be asking 'How to access multiple classes', not how to do/create.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then use css like selectors. It returns the first element of all selected elements. If you want to return all you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
 document.querySelector(".exp-1,.exp-2,.exp-3,.exp-4");
```

Comment: thanks bro and how to put them in common line like (" .exp (1-2-3-4))"

Comment: Welcome :) . If you want to use a single selector for all these classes, you should prefer using attribute selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as mentioned in @Rajesh's answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `starts with` selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^=exp-]')
```

#### Sample

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class^=t]'), function(el) {
  console.log(el.innerHTML)
})
```

```html
<div class="t1">1</div>
<div class="t2">2</div>
<div class="t3">3</div>
<div class="t4">4</div>
```

Comment: At least comment if something is wrong/missing. Revenge votes never help anyone.